# How to disable one element in jquery selectable?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery [selectable](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) . I am fetching JSON data via ajax and the I am building up the selectable elements dynamically. I need to keep only one element (div) disabled among all the selectable elements. Here is my code:-

```
if(session_type == 'oo') {
    var html = '<div class="selectable">';
    for(var sh = 0; sh < data.data.length; sh++ )
    {
        var fromTimeAMArr = data.data[sh].seeker_stime.split(' ');
        var fromTimeArr   = fromTimeAMArr[0].split(':')

        if (data.data[sh].booking_over != 1) {
            if (data.data[sh].in_cart == 0) {
                html += '<div class="time-slot-row" id="time-' + data.data[sh].id + '">';
            } else {
                html += '<div class="time-slot-row ui-selectee ui-selected" id="time-' + data.data[sh].id + '">';
            }
        }
        html += '<div class="time-slot"><span>' + data.data[sh].seeker_stime + '</span></div>';
        html += '<div class="time-book" data-id="' + data.data[sh].id + '"></div>';
        html += '<div class="time-view" id="t-' + data.data[sh].id + '">';
        html += '<div class="slot-from-time">';
        html += '<span class="time-box">' + fromTimeArr[0] + '</span>:<span class="time-box">' + fromTimeArr[1] + '</span>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="slot-gap">-</div>';
        html += '<div class="slot-to-time">';
        html += '<span class="time-box">09</span>:<span class="time-box">30</span>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="slot-remove" data-id="' + data.data[sh].id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
    $('#schedule_list_for_private_booking').append(html);

    $('.selectable').bind("mousedown", function(e) {e.metaKey = true;})
                    .selectable({
                            filter: ".time-slot-row:first",
                            selected: function(event, ui){    
                                if(ui.selected.id.length > 0)
                                {
                                    alert(ui.selected.id); 
                                }
                                
                            },
                            unselected: function(event, ui){
                                if(ui.unselected.id.length > 0)
                                {
                                    alert(ui.unselected.id);
                                }
                            }
                    });
  
}
```

However, I am still unable to keep one element disabled while creating the selectable elements dynamically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` option of the jquery-ui selectable plugin. More Informations do you find at the [docs of jquery-ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter).

I have created a simple example here, which I hope will help you.

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  $target = $('#selectable');

$target.selectable({
  // define which options will be disabled
  filter: ':not(.ui-disabled)',
});

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  $target.append('<li>Item ' + ('0' + items[i]).slice(-2) + '</li>');
}

// just for testing add the disabled class to one item
$target.find('li').eq(2).addClass('ui-disabled');

// refresh the your selectable
$target.selectable('refresh');
```

```css
#selectable {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#selectable li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#selectable li.ui-selected {
  background-color: #0c0;
  color: #fff;
}

#selectable li.ui-disabled {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ol id="selectable"></ol>
```